# Visual studio 2015 enterprise - Remove from layout strange window called "[-'filenamecurrentlyopened'-]"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 enterprise. Each time I open a file, it is also opened a strange windows with name "[-'filenamecurrentlyopened'-]", as you can see in the attached image [capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7jl4.png). I have tried reset window layout without success. How can I remove this window?

Comment: It appears to have an exit button (cross) on the top right. What happens if you click that?

Comment: The exit button closes the window, but it appears again when a reopen the file